# How to make a list of all the cached files and untracked files in a git repository?

Tags: git

`git ls-files` does not provide a way to do this, so I come up with this:

`git ls-files; git status --porcelain | grep ^?? | cut -d' ' -f2`

But I wonder if there is a git native to do this to make it portable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simple trick (using [`git clean`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean)):

```
git clean -n -d -x
```

That would list (as to be removed) all ignored and private files.

But that isn't based on a plumbing command.

Maybe:

```
git ls-files --others --exclude-standard -z
```

(From [git-ready](http://gitready.com/beginner/2009/01/16/cleaning-up-untracked-files.html))

```
--others             lists untracked files
--exclude-standard   uses .gitignore and the default git excludes
-z                   null-delimited output
```

Comment: But `git clean -nd` does not print a simple list.

Comment: @Bohr but you can awk/cut it like you were doing with git ls-files (except it is easier since you just need to remove the "Would remove " part at the beginning of each line)

Comment: Thanks, that's a little improvement, but still not portable.

Comment: @Bohr however, I have edited the answer with a more complete use of `git ls-files`